# FastAPI deploy in heroku giving an error h10

Tags: heroku, fastapi

I am trying to deploy a trial fastAPI application on heroku:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')

def get_root():
  return {'message': 'this is the root message'}
```

my root folder would look as:

```
venv/
main.py
Procfile
requierements.txt
```

inside main.py I have the code stated above, the Procfile contains;

```
web: uvicorn main:app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=${PORT:-5000}
```

and requierements.txt

```
fastapi
```

in the logs, when I access the root, I see;

```
2021-08-12T10:19:21.594055+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myappname.herokuapp.com request_id=7af272bc-7d23-41f3-a42e-afe380722f18 fwd="95.169.227.233" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: I'm having similar issues. Apparently, hard-setting your port is one of the many reasons why it crashes. Try changing your `Procfile` to just `web: uvicorn main:app`. Having said this, I'm still getting the same error with a very minimum FastAPI app.

Comment: my problem, in this case was that I had not add some libraries imported in main.py to requierements.txt

Comment: Thank God you got that straight because while finding Heroku very convenient and surprisingly quick, I think that the crash feedback leaves something to be desired. I actually ^C^V'ed _your_ `Procfile`, and that's when mine started working, so ignore my lame previous comment, don't change it and thank you very much!

Comment: yep, it is crashing again when trying to connect to a postgres database through SQLAchemy and the lack of feedback is truly annoying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should rename `requierements.txt` (*there is an extra 'e' in filename*) to `requirements.txt`. Because "Heroku automatically recognizes your app as a Python app if it includes a requirements.txt, setup.py or Pipfile file in its root directory." ([*](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#recognizing-a-python-app))

And then you should add `uvicorn` into your `requirements.txt`.